# How can I write this SQL SELECT query for this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this situation in a certain table:

```
id   |    name
1        'Test'
2        'Test'
3        'Test'
```

How can I make a query to `SELECT` by distinct the name? I also need the ID column, even if I get the first occurrence of the element, e.g. "if the name column repeats, give me the first record with this repetition."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select name, MIN(ID)
from aCertainTable
group by name
```